# PyUIの使い方

Tags: python

PyUIの使い方がわかる人がいたら教えてください。‍♂️
http://pyui.sourceforge.net/

追記：

このサンプルコードのtestoptとはなんですか。
教えてください。

```
import testopt
import time
import pyui

def onbutton(self):
    print "got a button " 

def run():
    opts = testopt.parseCommandLine(800, 600)
    done = 1
    frame = 0
    t = time.time()
    pyui.init(*opts)
    w = pyui.widgets.Frame(50, 50, 400, 400, "clipme")
    b = pyui.widgets.Button( "A button is here", onbutton)
    w.addChild(b)
    w.pack()

    w.setBackImage("max.bmp")
    pyui.run()

    print "done"
    pyui.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

（コードの出典： http://pyui.sourceforge.net/ の Example Code）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんなのが見つかりました。書かれている説明からすると何か関連してそうです。
[PySBD/testopt.py](https://github.com/bcamellia/PySBD/blob/master/testopt.py)

> ```
> """Process command line arguments for pyui test programs
> Command line options to this are:
>     -w window/screen width
>     -h window/screen height
>     -f fullscreen flag (0 or 1)
>     -r renderer ("dx" or other PyUI renderer)
> """
> ```

なお、`testopt`に関しては載っていないし中途半端ですが[Documentation](http://pyui.sourceforge.net/frame.html)があるようです。

しかし最新リリース版が[17年前](https://pypi.org/project/PyUI/)/開発版?も[類似時期(せいぜい+半年)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyui/files/pyui/)で、対応版数もPython 2.1, PyGame 1.1 では知っている人は居ないか、今では役に立たないライブラリなのでは？

---

`testopt`に関しては呼び出した後、

```
opts = testopt.parseCommandLine(800, 600)
```

使われているのがこれなので、

```
pyui.init(*opts)
```

`pyui.init()`のパラメータを作っているということでしょうね。

Documentationの **PyUI Basics Section** の最初に以下の説明があり、3つ目/4つ目の順番が上記と逆ですが、上記のソースで戻り値の順番を見ると以下と同じであり、途中の処理で対処されているか、説明だけちょっとおかしいようです。

> **Initializing PyUI**
>
> PyUI programs must call the pyui.init() method to initialize PyUI. This method creates a renderer which created the main window, and sets up PyUI internals ready to run the program. It may also switch to full-screen mode if that was specified. The arguments to pyui.init() are:
>
> width - the width of the main window in pixels
>   height - the height of the main window in pixels
>   renderer - the name of the renderer to use
>   fullscreen - a flag to specify whether to enter fullscreen mode
>
> The renderers that come with PyUI are:
>
> "null" - A null renderer that doesn't actually renderer anything
>   "2d" - PyGame two-dimensional renderer
>   "gl" - an OpenGL renderer implemented using PyOpenGL
>   "tk" - a Tk canvas renderer. (experimental)
>   "win32" - a win32 GDI renderer (experimental)
>
> A "dx" Direct 3D renderer written in C++ also exists, but it is not included in the PyUI distribution.
>
> For example, to initialize PyUI in fullscreen OpenGL mode at 640x480 resolution:
>
> pyui.init(640, 480, "gl", 1)